# secure file transfer from client to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, file-transfer

I have a client that would like to securely transfer their sales data to our AWS S3 space.  The initial data dump could be up to 20GB and then periodic file transfers that are much smaller.  Can someone recommend an easy process for the client that we can set up to manage the one-time data dump and ongoing data transfers?

Thank you all for your advice,
RR

Comment: Is your client on Windows or Linux? What is there level of technical expertise regarding ongoing transfers?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: They are using Windows.  I should assume their technical expertise is low.   For the first data dump, I would like it to be user friendly.  For an example, browser based.  I'm thinking an ideal set up would be to pass a URL to the client, they click the link which takes them to a simple file upload page.  For ongoing transfers, not sure yet.

Comment: Why not mount an S3 bucket to a local drive, and let them manage with normal windows file management tools? Nice thing about a local file system mount is the can, explore folder, view files, etc. File access permissions can be controlled/defined as needed.  Can't do that with an upload form. Would that approach work for your client?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo.  You are referring to installing software like CyberDuck and Cloudberry on the clients machine, correct?  I think this sounds like the quickest way to implementation.  It will probably be the route I will choose.  Though, it will still be nice to also do this through a browser as the client would not have to install anything on local machine. --- Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the secure transfer using pre-signed URL's. please follow this Developers guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Do you believe this would work with a front end browser?  For example, I would like to send a link to the client, they navigate to a simple front end that steps them through a file upload process.

Comment: Yes it will work the Pre Signed process needs to be added to the backend of the upload functionality for the application.